# Flutter web: The Image.memory makes the web page freeze for a period of time when uploading/downloading an image that has a big size

Tags: flutter, image, flutter-web, flutter-image

When a user uploads an image that has a big size, the application will freeze at the moment(Is the app calculating?).

How to fix it to smooth. The Image.network has a leadingBuilder property but the Image.memory doesn't have this property.

And another similar problem. When the Image.memory is assigned in the x parameter and another widget is y. When I use setState for swapping the widget x and y in the Card widget. The web always freezes for a while that the widget swap from y to x(From another widget to Image.memory widget that
contain the image with big size).

The example:
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/59549741/165982975-51cbbe78-1c3e-4392-95a0-2654395c68b3.mp4

Comment: you could try [precacheImage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html) but i am quite uncertain if it changes anything...

Comment: Hi @pskink, thank you for your method.
This method doesn't help in uploading an image.
I think this method is suitable to show the image that was downloaded. I can use this method on another page. Thank you so much.

Comment: I tried precacheImage. The web still freezes for a while when I assigned the Image widget in the x parameter before using precacheImage(x.image, context). I think the problem is Image.memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is technical.
Follow at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/102828